# How can i get last message at inbox?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

How can i create inbox? I can't find a answer.

```
public function inbox()
{
  $user = Auth::user();
  $messages = Message::where('sender_id', '=', $user->id)
  ->orWhere('receiver_id', '=', $user->id)
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->get(['sender_id', 'message', 'created_at'])
  ->groupBy('sender_id');
}
```

My table:

```
id | sender_id | receiver_id | message | created_at | updated_at
```

If i send a message, showing my name at list, not recevier name.

Comment: Laravel has a last() method

Answer (score 0):

Try it ,add latest() method

```
public function inbox()
{
  $user = Auth::user();
  $messages = Message::where('sender_id', '=', $user->id)
  ->orWhere('receiver_id', '=', $user->id)
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->get(['sender_id', 'message', 'created_at'])
  ->groupBy('sender_id')
  ->latest()
   ->get();
}
```